# How to write a simple object in PHP

Tags: php, variables, object

this is quite an easy question but I couldn't seem to find a proper answer.

Let's say I am writing in actionScript 3 an object like this:

```
var myCar = new Object();
myCar.engine = "Nice Engine";
myCar.numberOfDoors = 4;
myCar.howFast= 150;
```

how do I write such a thing in PHP?

Answer (score 31):

```
$myCar = new stdClass;
$myCar->engine = 'Nice Engine';
$myCar->numberOfDoors = 4;
$myCar->howFast = 150;
```

Have a look at the [documentation for objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) for a more in-depth discussion.

Comment: @phpmeh: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question   pointing to some other place is ok, as long as you include a relevant snippet/excerpt here.

Answer (score 12):

You can either use classes, like:

```
class Car {

public $engine;
public $numberOfDoors;
public $howFast;

}
$myCar = new Car();
$myCar->engine = 'Nice Engine';
$myCar->numberOfDoors = 4;
$myCar->howFast = 150;
```

or if you need this object only for property storage, you could use an associative array, like:

```
 $myCar['engine'] = "Nice engine";
 $myCar['numberOfDoors'] = 4;
 $myCar['howFast'] = 150;
```

Comment: Ignoring the array part of this answer... this is the best answer.  It depends on your php settings, but explicitly declaring your class variables can save you a bunch of headache when in the future you turn warnings on for uninitialized variables.

Comment: Being a actionscript dev myself I've encountered many situations in small projects where generic objects are sufficient and save a lot of time compared to classes. Keeping that in mind php's asociative array is imho the best representation of such object in AS3 so I wonder if the array part should be ignored.

Comment: I was ignoring the array bit because the OP was asking in the context of objects.  :)